# Is there an idiomatic way to convert a Class to an Object when the class relies on an implicit?

Tags: scala, singleton, implicit, scalatest

I'm new to Scala.

I have a series of test classes that perform UI tests, and a series of classes that contain reusable helper methods.

Example Test Class:

```scala
class MyCoolTestClass extends FreeSpec {

    //Note:  This driver needs to be configurable by the test in some way.
    implicit val driver:WebDriver = new ChromeDriver()

    val myCoolPage = new MyCoolPage

    //Tests below rely on myCoolPage methods
}
```

Example Helper Class:

```
class MyCoolPage(implicit driver:WebDriver) {
    def clickElement1(){
     //relies on driver
    }
    def assertElement2Enabled(){
     //relies on driver
    }
}
```

Now, none of the helper classes actually have mutable state.  This makes me want to convert them from `class`es to `object`s.

However, the only way I can figure out how to do this is to add an `implicit WebDriver` argument to every method.  That works, but it's ugly.  Are there any more concise ways to achieve what I want here?  Alternatively, is there a more idiomatic way to organize this Test Class / Helper Method relationship entirely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd argue, there is **no idiomatic way** to convert the `class`es to `object`s, as you are asking. And here is my point of view on why:

You declared an attribute `driver` in `MyCoolClass`, you are using in the methods. Therefore your `class` actually has state. The `WebDriver` is [state injected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) into `MyCoolPage`. Depending on the implementation of the injected `WebDriver`, the way method calls are handled may vary.

To overcome this, you'd need to give the `WebDriver` as implicit argument to each of your methods, as you found out by yourself. However, this would allow to externally replace the driver during runtime. This would violate the [Open-Closed-Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open%E2%80%93closed_principle), which I'd argue is even **less idiomatic** than using your `class` construct.

If you encounter this problem again in the future, you might try to write the code without the use of `implicit`. If it still seems like an appropriate way to change `class` to `object`, you are probably good to go.

Comment: I hate that there's just one piece of state that's preventing me from making these methods static, but that's how it is.

Answer (score 2):

You *can* change your help classes into objects and still provide an `implicit` value to member methods.

```
object MyCoolPage {

  private val driver :WebDriver = implicitly[WebDriver]

  def clickElement1() = ???          //relies on driver
  def assertElement2Enabled() = ???  //relies on driver
}
```

But then the `implicit` declaration has to move out of the test class. Two possibilities come to mind: the `WebDriver` object...

```
object WebDriver {
  implicit val wd :WebDriver = new ChromeDriver()
  ...
```

...or in a dedicated object.

```
object MyCoolPage {
  import MyTestImplicits._
  private val driver :WebDriver = implicitly[WebDriver]
  ...
```

All in all, I'm not convinced it's going to be worth the effort.

Comment: I like this idea, but given that I don't know what further changes we'll make regarding how we use WebDrivers I'm not sure it's the right move to take that control away from the testclass.  I'll keep this in mind as things evolve.

Answer (score 1):

Consider turning `MyCoolPage` into a trait with an abstract implicit driver field like so

```
trait MyCoolPage {
  implicit val driver: WebDriver

  def clickElement1() = {
    //relies on driver
  }

  def assertElement2Enabled(){
    //relies on driver
  }
}
```

Then have `MyCoolTestClass` extend `MyCoolPage` and override `driver` field with custom-configured driver as follows

```
class MyCoolTestClass extends FreeSpec with MyCoolPage {
  override implicit val driver: WebDriver = new ChromeDriver()

  //Tests below rely on myCoolPage methods
}
```

Now `MyCoolTestClass` has access to every method from `MyCoolPage`, and those methods do not need an implicit driver parameter.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work, because then the test class has no control over which driver is used.  We need to be able to customize the driver with headless options and/or test in other browsers.  I'll make that more clear in the question.

Comment: I don't think that modification would give me any of the benefits of the Singleton design pattern.  It's still instanced, just with an is-a vs. a has-a relationship.

Answer (score 0):

> Now, none of the helper classes actually have mutable state. This makes me want to convert them from `class`es to `object`s.

But they do have state. Yes, it's immutable, but so is the state of most case classes, `Option`s, `List`s... None of them should be converted into `object`s. I don't think there is a solution which is really better than the one you started with.

However, here is an option: nesting the helper objects in a superclass:

```
abstract class AbstractTestClass extends FreeSpec {
  // may optionally be implicit or non-abstract
  val driver: WebDriver 

  object MyCoolPage {
    def clickElement1(){
      //relies on driver
    }
    def assertElement2Enabled(){
      //relies on driver
    }
  }

  object MyCoolPage2 ...
}

class MyCoolTestClass extends AbstractTestClass {
  override val driver: WebDriver = new ChromeDriver()

  // can use MyCoolPage methods
}
```

Note that `object`s are loaded lazily, so if `MyCoolTestClass` doesn't use `MyCoolPage2` it won't pay for it. The trade-off is that all helper classes have to be defined in a single file.